# Ignoring some entity fields during saving in Objectify 4

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use Objectify @IgnoreSave annotation along with simple If condition (IfEmpty, IfNull) but it seems that it is not working. Without If condition the actual value is not persisted as expected, however, when I use some If condition, it is always persisted (e.g. if IfNull condition used and null value provided, it is persisted and hence original value in datastore deleted).

```
...
@IgnoreSave(IfNull.class)
private String email;
...

...
this.objectify.save().entity(userDetails).now();
...
```

Is there any additional configuration needed? Or has anyone experienced the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From "hence original value in datastore deleted" it sounds like you misunderstand a fundamental characteristic of the GAE datastore - entities are stored whole. If you @IgnoreSave a field, it will be ignored during save and thus the field will not be present in the datastore. You do not get to update some fields and not others.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. I know that characteristic of GAE Datastore but I probably did not get the right purpose of @IgnoreSave annotation. I thought that at background it works like that - when it is used along with for example IfNull condition then in case of null value for the given field during saving, Objectify executes "hidden load" to get the original entity and uses its value of the given field to overwrite null in provided entity. Then the entity is stored as a whole.

Comment: Objectify tries to avoid "magic" as much as possible and generally just does what you tell it. It never loads an entity unless you explicitly tell it to load, and never saves an entity unless you explicitly tell it to save. @IgnoreSave just does exactly that - ignores the field on save.

Comment: Now it is clear to me. Then I will have to handle such situations on my own. Thank you for your time.